this method implicitly uses cas policy error when printing
i use a .net based app in my office. when i want to print a paper from application that uses activereport it shows error :
this method implicitly uses CAS policy which has been absoleted be the .NET Framework in order to enable  CAS policy for compatible reasons please use netfx40_legacysecuritypolicy configuration switch .
but my application dose not has config file to write netfx40_legacysecuritypolicy enabled =true
how can i fix this error ? thanks to your helps
